# How to freeze a tableView cell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I want to freeze a tableView cell on top of screen, so that while scrolling, other cells move but the top cell stays on its place.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        cell. //I think it must be here
        return cell
```

Thank you.

Comment: Create table view header.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: you can take TableView header. Even you can take a static view and below it add your_table_view. In static view add your label, searchbar etc whatever you what.

Comment: u checked the code @SinaSJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these methods to create tableview header and add any subviews in it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = UIView.init()
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    //Add subviews here
    return header
}
```

Comment: I also want to set first column as header. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 65
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
header.textLabel?.text="adadafaf"//ur data
}
```